# Is there any Win32 API to hide and show a menu-item at runtime?

Tags: winapi, menu, menuitem

I have loaded menu from the resource file:

```
IDR_MENU1 MENU DISCARDABLE 
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "Menuitem1", IDM_CTX_M1
    MENUITEM "Menuitem2", IDM_CTX_M2
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "Menuitem3", IDM_CTX_M3
    MENUITEM "Menuitem4", IDM_CTX_M4
END
```

-

```
hMenu = LoadMenu(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
```

Is there any Win32 API to hide/show a menu-item by its resource-id?

For example IDM_CTX_M1...

Comment: You can enable and disable menu items, but you cannot hide items. You'd have to remove them altogether, and add them back when you need them. [About menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus) explains how this is done.

Comment: There are a functions to get menu-items by position. But how to get menu-item by identifier (for example IDM_CTX_M1)?

Comment: [GetMenuItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenuiteminfow).

Answer (score 0):

You can call RemoveMenu function to remove this menu item completely

```
BOOL RemoveMenu(
  [in] HMENU hMenu,
  [in] UINT  uPosition,
  [in] UINT  uFlags
);
```